# Android draw circle around circular button

Tags: android, xml, view

I'm trying to create a custom joystick using a button that I will (hopefully) center inside of  circular view. Problem is, I can't figure out how to center them on each other.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_states"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/joystick_border"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

This makes them display as

[image: joystick]

Since there's apparently no `alignCenter` I'm not sure how to center them. Anyone know how?

Comment: Instead of trying to align 2 Views... make them a single View!

Comment: Right, but I'd like to move the smaller one while keeping the border stationary

Comment: Then, since you are apparently setting them inside a RelativeLayout, why not simply set both to `canterInParent="true"`? Obviously, after dropping all the other alignments, centerings and margins.

Comment: Well, I'll want to move that, so maybe put both in a RelativeLayout inside the main layout?

Comment: If they aren't inside a RelativeLAyout, then all your current alignments and centerings won't work anyway. This is why I *supposed* they were in a RelativeLayout. And yes, this could be a solution. Or you could make a custom View with a fixed border and a movable part.

Comment: I meant a relative inside a relative. I tried it, graphically it works well, however I'm noticing it has its own sort of border cut off, like the relative layout is it's own little pane. I was under the impression layouts only mattered up until onCreate but it would appear not so

Comment: Mind that you might have *paddings* set in the dimens files.

Comment: Well here's a link to my most recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37202959/6191359    I'd really appreciate your input, since its basically the result of this question but with new annoying errors

Comment: I'd probably end up with 8 **fixed** round buttons around a central one (fire or whatever)... ;) Some UI ideas: https://www.google.com/search?q=joystick&biw=1280&bih=662&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9q6HK1dbMAhUESCYKHbGVDqkQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1.25#tbm=isch&q=virtual+joystick

Comment: Meanwhile, I found [this](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=joystick).